# how to processing image like mnist using python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, neural-network

I'm making digit recoginition model using mnist.
learning is quite well, model's accuarcy is about 98.6%.
But, when i test other images(not mnist image), the accuarcy is very low

This is my code processing the image.
the image what i want to use is IAM dataset. here is a link.
http://www.fki.inf.unibe.ch/databases/iam-handwriting-database

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from glob import glob
from skimage import color
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from scipy.misc import imresize


def read_image(path):
    image = io.imread(path, as_grey= 1)
    image_resized = imresize(image, [28, 28])
    image_reshaped = image_resized.reshape([784])
    image_reshaped = np.array(image_reshaped, dtype= np.float32)

    for i in range(len(image_reshaped)):
        if image_reshaped[i] >= 255:
            image_reshaped[i] = 0
        elif image_reshaped[i] != 255:
            image_reshaped[i] /= 255.0000
    return image_reshaped

testing_image = read_image(path)
plt.imshow(a.reshape((28, 28)))
```

[image]

this is my processing image(sorry for link, i'm newbee, so i can't upload directly)

[image]

and this is mnist image.

so, my question is, what's the different of my images and mnist images,
and how can i make my images like mnist images?

Comment: You cannot expect your model to generalize to data which is significantly different from the data you trained it on. Why don't you retrain on the other dataset?

Answer (score 0):

The model related to MNIST isn't able to generalize to different images! As you can see the '7' in your data is completely different from the one in the MNIST set. I would suggest you to create a new ANN and train it with the AIM dataset.